# extract file content from match pattern to another match pattern

Tags: linux, bash, awk

How to extract file content from match pattern to another match pattern. Not just split.

For example:

1.txt

```
myname
myage
myeducation
myaddress
> myoccupation
mydesignation
mysalary
myofficename
> mygrosssalary
mypermanentaddress
myfathersname
```

in above file i want to extract content to another file and remove content starting from pattern

```
> myoccupation
```

to

```
> mygrosssalary
```

to another file.

Comment: Inclusive or exclusive of either or both delimiting lines? Show your expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk '/> myoccupation/,/> mygrosssalary/' file
```

With sed:

```
sed -n '/> myoccupation/,/> mygrosssalary/p' file
```

And you can use output redirection to create another file, with

```
comand ... > newfile
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i -e '/> myoccupation/,/> mygrosssalary/{w newfile' -e 'd}' file
```